# Looking for an integer for which the $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ contains elements with certain orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I don't need a specific answer or whatever, but I'm looking for a strategy to solve this kind of problems.

The specific question I have in mind is:

Give an integer $n$ for which the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* $ contains elements that has order $4$, (some) elements of order $5$, but no elements of order $3$.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way but my idea is to try $n = p$ prime. Then $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ has $p-1$ elements and is cyclic.

In order for there to be an element of order $3$ you must have that $3| p-1$ (since if a prime divides the order of a group then there exists an element of that prime order). So for there NOT to be an element of order $3$ you would have to have that $p=3$ or $p\equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

Similarly you must have $p\equiv 1 \bmod 5$ to have an element of order $5$ (eliminating the $p=3$ possibility)

Since our group is cyclic then an element of order $4$ existing is equivalent to $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (this wouldn't have worked for general $n$, the cyclic property is important).

So our prime must satisfy $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $p\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and $p\equiv 1 \bmod 5$. The simultaneous solution is $p\equiv 41 \bmod 60$ so $p=41$ will work and so will any other prime in this class.

This argument will ALWAYS give you a prime that works.

Comment: Why is the simultaneous solution $41 \text{ mod} 60$?

Comment: Elementary number theory. The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees a unique solution mod $61$ and by observation $41$ satisfies all of the congruence conditions.

Comment: thats fine, but what kind of observation? How do we get 41?

Comment: There is an algorithm that gives 41 but trial and error works. We know there is a unique class mod $61$ satisfying all three congruences, so it remains to find a number $1\leq n\leq 60$ such that $n$ satisfies the three congruences, clearly $n= 41$ works...

Answer (score 1):

This implies that $4|\phi (n),5|\phi (n)$ but $3$ does not divide $\phi (n)$.This is because of the fact that order of $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{nZ})^*$ has $\phi (n)$ elements and order of each element of a group divides the order of the group.

One such $n$ is $41$ because $\phi(41)=40$(As $41$ is a prime) and $4|40,5|40$ but $3$ does not divide $40$ and as $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{41Z})^*$ is cyclic so $\exists $ elements of order $4,5$ but not $3$

Here $\phi $ is the Euler's phi function denoting the number of integers less than n and coprime to n.

Comment: I know that a element cannot have an order which is not a divisor of the order of the group. But the reverse does also hold? If $k$ is a divisor of the order of some group, then there must exist an element in that group that has order $k$ ? thanks for your help

Comment: No the reverse doesn't always hold .Though it holds for prime because in that case the groups are cyclic.

Comment: This is not true in general, but a slightly weaker property is called [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29).

Comment: Also, requiring the number $k$ not to divide $\varphi(n)$ actually guarantees that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ can not have an element of order $k$; even if it might rule out some values of $n$. In other words, this condition is sufficient, but might not be necessary.

Comment: Why exactly are the multiplicative prime groups cyclic?

Comment: *I had made a small mistake in the earlier comment which I have edited now.*I think it needs some field theory along with the fact that $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$ to prove it .

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu: So the best method is, looking for all prime numbers from 2, 3, 5, 7 .... until we found some prime $p$ such that 4 and 5 divides $p-1$ but 3 doesn't...? What if we had instead of 3,4,5 numbers like 13, 15 and 18 (so not 13 doesnt divide $Zn^*$, but 15 and 18 do..? By the way, has this anything to do with sylow-p-groups?

Comment: And second question, what if we did not know anything about cyclic groups? I cannot find it in my book, so there must be another way to solve this without considering cyclic groups and their properties